# IP address to binary in C

Tags: c, ip-address

I have an ip address like so:

```
address = '192.168.1.11';
```

and need to convert it to its binary format

```
11000000 10101000 00000001 00001011
```

I have some ideas on how to leftshift the decimal number and using inet_addr, but not sure how I would go about doing it.

Thanks, I'm still new to C.

Comment: Do you want to print the binary strings, or just have the 4 numbers available separately?  The hard part is converting an 8-bit number to a string of binary digits; there isn't a simple function in standard C that does that AFAIK.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I suspect that the OP actually just wants to convert it to a native integer type, not into "binary format". Most people are confused around the concept of representations.

Comment: You don't want to parse "through" the '.'; the '.' tells you when you've come to the end of a number. You would get better help if you were to post some code so people could see where you're having trouble.

Comment: A native integer type is something like `char`, `short`, `int`, `long`, etc. Since you need bits, that's what you want. When you talk about a "format" and show it as 0's and 1's and spaces, that looks like a character string and that's how Jonathan interpreted it. Note that, while the hardware presents numbers as a bunch of bits, they don't have a "format" ... they are just as much octal or hex as they are binary. So you want something with the value 0xC0A8010B

Comment: i see. Thanks for your suggestions. I'll be clearer next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a socket function specific for transforming text IP into a 32-bit "longip" address, but this might be unecessary in this context. A simple form would be to parse it using [`sscanf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/):

```
char ip[] = "192.168.1.11";
int n1, n2, n3, n4;
sscanf(ip, "%d.%d.%d.%d", &n1, &n2, &n3, &n4).

// Result:

// n1 = 192
// n2 = 168
// n3 = 1
// n4 = 11
```

Comment: This code does not provide a way to check if an IP is valid.

Comment: This code does not answer the question at all. OP is asking for a conversion to binary this code just takes in an IP address???

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`inet_addr(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/inet_addr) function to convert the string into an `in_addr_t`, and then convert that to binary.  There's no standard library function to convert a number to binary, but it's pretty straightforward to do yourself using the bitwise logical operators.

Comment: I've looked through the doc but not sure how to convert the in_addr_t to binary? Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: `inet_addr` converts a string to a 32-bit int in network byte order, but there's no indication that the OP wants that, and it would be hard to use it in a machine (endian) -independent way.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it:

```
char *addrc = '127.0.0.1';
in_addr_t addri = inet_addr(addrc);
__bswap_32(addri); /* ommit if network byte order == host order */
char addrb[40];
itoa(addri,addrb,2);
printf("%s = %s (binary)",addrc,addrb);
```

Comment: You've made typo, it's `in_addr_t`. But this works nicely. Its written in wrong order tho.